# What is "Service extensions" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes

The above page has the following explanation.
In debug mode,Service extensions are enabled.
in release mode,Service extensions are disabled.
what is "Service extensions" in Flutter?

Comment: if the answer below helped you, consider marking it as the accepted answer. We can help others with the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Service Extension are a set of tools that provide additional debugging capabilities, For example `debugAllowBanner`, `debugDumpApp`, `debugDumpRenderTree`,`debugPaint` etc.

You can find the full list of these service extension at the source link below.

[Source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/flutter/+/v0.8.7/packages/flutter/test/foundation/service_extensions_test.dart)